# How do you deal with aggressive and rude (irrelevant) questions in a conference?

Tags: conference, communication

I was at a conference recently as a member of the audience and during the Q & A segment, an audience member (unsolicited) jumped up and said that the presentation was 'absolutely wrong' quite aggressively. The presenter (junior scholar) was mortified.

Can I ask if you have a particular way of responding to questions that are aggressive or ad hominem attacks without being seen as defensive particularly if the person asking the question is someone senior and respected?

Comment: "That's just like.. your opinion, man!"

Comment: "I don't think so. You see, because the wrkzwft is indeed quite zvowefi, it may sometimes appear that qozidsf, but, of course, when the covfefe strikes, it can of course happen that zVfase goes wrong. However, this is not the typical case. Rather, quite counterintuitively zvoijs goes towards qpoifeff, and then all our intuitions are off and you have to rely on the computation. I am happy to discuss more during the break."

Comment: “Thank you for giving me a chance to address this. I have spent a lot of time considering this point and .... “